# Trigger jQuery Image Loader when sort items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jail Image loader (https://github.com/sebarmeli/JAIL) to load my images. In that page, I have a Sortable image gallery, too.

How do I trrigger the Jail plugin when I "sort" the gallery items?

Here I call `jail()` for every image with class "lazy":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function(){
        $('img.lazy').jail();
    });
</script>
```

Here is my Sortable script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Portfolio = {
        sort: function(items) {
            items.show();
            $('#portfolio-content').find('div.portfolio-item').not(items).fadeOut(500);
        },
        showAll: function(items) {
            items.fadeIn(500);
        },
        doSort: function() {
            $('a', '#portfolio-sort').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var $a = $(this);
                if (!$a.is('#all')) {
                    var items = $('div[data-cat=' + $a.data('cat') + ']', '#portfolio-content');
                    Portfolio.sort(items);
                } else {
                    Portfolio.showAll($('div.portfolio-item', '#portfolio-content'));
                }
            });
        }
    };

    Portfolio.doSort();    
});
```

Here is my page, but this don't work very well, if you see the images don't appears when you sort the galley, only if you scroll down the page:

http://alsite.com.br/angelo/galeria.asp

Comment: Consider loading your images another way that uses less bandwidth. Loading your webpage took me over a minute and my internet isn't that slow. Even for the ones that are onscreen it takes longer than it should.

Comment: humm, but this "Jail" Plugin do that. THis load only the images that are on the viewport. I have 2mb conection speed here, and don't take a few seconds to load the page..